# 依存していないjarに存在する具象クラスインスタンスをDIしたい

Tags: java

Java8 (JavaEE7) を使って開発しています。
JavaEEのCDIを使って、「依存していないjarに存在する具象クラスのインスタンス」を注入したいです。
つまり：

＜business.jar＞

```
class BiusinessController {
    @Inject
    private Repository repository;
}

interface Repository { }
```

＜dataaccess.jar＞

```
class RepositoryImpl implements Repository
```

このように、business.jarとdataaccess.jarの依存の方向はdataaccess→businessです。
よって、このままではRepositoryImplが見つけられないため、注入できません。
諸事情から、この依存の方向は変えられないです。

このように、依存対象ではないjar（dataaccess.jar）に存在する具象クラス（`RepositoryImpl`）を注入するには、どうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

同じクラスローダでロードされているのであれば依存方向に関係なく注入できるのではないでしょうか？

#### Repository.java

```
public interface Repository
{
    String say();
}
```

#### RepositoryImpl.java

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class RepositoryImpl implements Repository
{
    public String say()
    {
        return "Hello !!";
    }
}
```

#### BusinessController.java

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BusinessController 
{    
    @Inject
    private Repository repository;

    public String greeting()
    {
        return repository.say();
    }
}
```

これらを下記の構成にしたアプリとしてデプロイした場合にgreetingメソッドは希望通り、「Hello !!」を返してくれます。

```
ROOT
 + WEB-INF
     + lib
         + business.jar
         + dataaccess.jar
     + web.xml
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。私の勘違いで動作していなかっただけでした。ご指摘の通り、libディレクトリにRepositoryImplクラス入りのjarが入ってさえいれば、DIコンテナが拾ってくれることを確認できました。